# JQuery `.after()` Renders HTML Rather Than Parsing It

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this jQuery (1.8.3) code:

```
$("input[title='test']")[0].after("<p><a href='#' onclick='doSomething();'>Encrypt</a></p>");
```

But it only renders text, not the actual HTML. 
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: You mean you actually want the HTML markup characters `<p><a href...` to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a particular element within the JQuery wrapped set via an index `[0]`, the returned element is a regular DOM element and not a JQuery object, so `after()` (or any other JQuery member) won't work on it.

Using array index notation against a JQuery wrapped set of objects is really just short-hand for making a JQuery **[`wrappedSet.get()` method call](https://api.jquery.com/get/)** (not to be confused with the **[`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)** method call).

If you re-wrap the resulting element in the JQuery object though, you can go back to working with it in JQuery.

Note that `$("input[title='test']")[0]` is wrapped with `$()`.

```js
$($("input[title='test']")[0]).after("<p><a href='#' onclick='doSomething();'>Encrypt</a></p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input title="test"/>
```